# How to pretty print a Vec<char> with separator?

Tags: rust, vector, pretty-print

I am trying to apply [`join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.join) (or something similar) to a `Vec<char>` in order to pretty print it.

What I came up with so far is this (and this does what I want):

```
let vec: Vec<char> = "abcdef".chars().collect();
let sep = "-";
let vec_str: String = vec
    .iter().map(|c| c.to_string()).collect::<Vec<String>>().join(sep);
println!("{}", vec_str);  // a-b-c-d-e-f
```

That seems overly complex (and allocates a `Vec<String>` that is not really needed).

I also tried to get `std::slice::join` to work by explicitly creating a slice:

```
let vec_str: String = (&vec[..]).join('-');
```

but here the compiler complains:

> method not found in `&[char]`

Is there a simpler way to create a printable `String` from a `Vec<char>` with a separator between the elements?

Comment: @Stargateur thanks! i had found that question but as the answer is pretty specific about `std::env::args()` at first i almost overlooked the helpful last part. so: yes, in a way the answer to my question is there but it is a bit hidden...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`intersperse`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.2/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.intersperse) from the itertools crate.

```
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.8.2

fn main() {
    let vec : Vec<_> = "abcdef".chars().collect();
    let sep = '-';
    let sep_str : String = vec.iter().intersperse(&sep).collect();
    println!("{}", sep_str);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=024f2c27a1effff4a0a6a049171eae03)

Comment: oh, thanks! is found `interleave` but not `intersperse` (which is *right* below!).